# How to set timeout on MySql query?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, database-administration

I have a shell script how execute some query on a big loop, but sometimes the script doesn't respond.
I want to add a timeout to Mysql query to prevent this bug.

```
$sql=`mysql --protocol=tcp --user=**** --password=\'****\' --host="vl*****1" --database="C***K" -e "UPDATE C****k SET current_status =\'$status\',last_state_change=\'$lastchange\' WHERE MC_internal_name=\'$InternalName\';"
```

Tkanks !

Comment: Find the error! If you start your script via cron you can better use EVENTS direct in MySQL. So the script only starts when server is up and running. You can also add a LIMIT to your SQL to prevent to run a long time. Check also via EXPLAIN if the query use Indexe

Answer (score 1):

Use option:

```
--connect-timeout=#
```

> Replace dash with number of seconds before connection timeout.